# Nearby Notifications interval between 2 consecutive notifications

Tags: android, google-nearby, google-beacon-platform

I have been trying out the nearby feature, i had configured my beacon with google beacon dashboard, i want to know is there any time delay between 2 consecutive notifications

Case 1: Near by notification is received by the device , users cancels the notification, then again user reaches the beacon zone is the notification is delivered to the user . is there any time interval ?

Case 2:Near by notification is received by device users opens the notification, the next time user comes to the beacon zone is the notification will be delivered, is there any time interval ?

Is there any possibility of controlling the interval between notifications in the google cloud platform.